# Unable to build the PostgreSQL environment. FATAL: database "t" does not exist

Tags: postgresql, psql

I installed postgres from brew.
I got an error, I tried to delete the postmaster.id
The file seems to be missing.

rm -f data/postmaster.pid
It had no effect.

### I tryed

```
$brew install postgres
```

```
$psql --version                                                                                                        
psql (PostgreSQL) 14.1

$postgres --version                                                                                                    
postgres (PostgreSQL) 14.1
```

```
$psql

psql: error: connection to server on socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: FATAL:  database "t" does not exist
```

```
$postgres -D /usr/local/var/postgres                                                                                  

2022-01-28 14:27:14.406 JST [94892] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 14.1 on aarch64-apple-darwin21.1.0, compiled by Apple clang version 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.3), 64-bit
2022-01-28 14:27:14.408 JST [94892] LOG:  could not bind IPv6 address "::1": Address already in use
2022-01-28 14:27:14.408 JST [94892] HINT:  Is another postmaster already running on port 5432? If not, wait a few seconds and retry.
2022-01-28 14:27:14.408 JST [94892] LOG:  could not bind IPv4 address "127.0.0.1": Address already in use
2022-01-28 14:27:14.408 JST [94892] HINT:  Is another postmaster already running on port 5432? If not, wait a few seconds and retry.
2022-01-28 14:27:14.408 JST [94892] WARNING:  could not create listen socket for "localhost"
2022-01-28 14:27:14.408 JST [94892] FATAL:  could not create any TCP/IP sockets
2022-01-28 14:27:14.409 JST [94892] LOG:  database system is shut down
```

```
$rm /usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid                                                                            

rm: /usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid: No such file or directory
```

```
$sudo lsof -i:5432                 
                                                                                    
COMMAND    PID USER   FD   TYPE            DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
postgres 94724    t    7u  IPv6 0xe42d991dab624b7      0t0  TCP localhost:postgresql (LISTEN)
postgres 94724    t    8u  IPv4 0xe42d991d7856c0f      0t0  TCP localhost:postgresql (LISTEN)
```

Comment: You have asked that question before, and the information you give is just as incomplete.

Comment: sorry,I looked up your solution to implement it, but I couldn't figure it out. Therefore, I asked the question again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why you insist in wrecking your PostgreSQL server by removing the PID file. I wish you would stop doing that.

The error message means that you are trying to connect to database `t`, but that database does not exist. Since you do not explicitly specify a database, the causes could be:

- you are operating system user `t`, so the connection defaults to database `t`
- the environment variable `PGDATABASE` is set to `t`
- the environment variable `PGUSER` is set to `t`, and the connection defaults to the same database name as the user name

In any event, the solution is to pick an existing database and use

```bash
psql -d dbname
```

To find out which databases actually exist on the server, you can use

```bash
psql -l
```

Comment: $psql -d dbname                                                                                                        

psql: error: connection to server on socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: FATAL:  database "dbname" does not exist

Comment: $psql -d t                                                   　　　　　　　　                                      　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　                                                      
psql: error: connection to server on socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: FATAL:  database "t" does not exist

Comment: sorry                                                                                                                            
$psql -d postgres             　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　                                                                                                   
psql (14.1)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=#

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe If you wanted to be helpful, you could have mentioned psql -l lists available databases.

Comment: @mccambridge Perhaps I had a bad day, and yes, your comment is helpful. I'll make sure to add it to the answer. I was annoyed that somebody would take my `dbname` literally.

Answer (score 0):

I am just exetending the answer give by @Laurenz Albe.

I installed the postgres@15 on my mac machine using brew.

I was also tyring to connect using the username "postgres" as it is specificed on the link I was following.

But later I realised that the defaule postgres DB created by the name of my machine.

And when I use my machine name as a username I am able to connect to DB in PgAdmin 4 as well.